# Kafka-Fabric-First-Network Problems

Tags: apache-kafka, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I'm trying to launch and create my first fabric network with Kafka consensum.
Here is the link of the network and the instructions I am following

```
Kafka-Fabric-First-Network
https://github.com/skcript/Kafka-Fabric-Network
```

All configurations seem to be correct but when I launch the network with the following script

```
# Start the network see start.sh script for details
sudo ./start.sh
```

I receive the following error message.

```
2018-06-29 08:21:16.428 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 009 Sign: digest: 83F4528319E8FE2F99E1FB34C00C30F52E66EB2CAB242B1F0F644473959C1AA7 
2018-06-29 08:21:16.429 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 00a Returning existing local MSP
2018-06-29 08:21:16.429 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 00b Obtaining default signing identity
2018-06-29 08:21:16.429 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 00c Returning existing local MSP
2018-06-29 08:21:16.432 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 00d Obtaining default signing identity
2018-06-29 08:21:16.435 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 00e Sign: plaintext: 0AC3060A1508021A0608FCD7D7D90522...15BB3FC5DE447115057D7C6BA797D942 
2018-06-29 08:21:16.447 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 00f Sign: digest: D29A93597779809F220272FB3252A83D2D690BB35091DC6D60FE8C62D73A79F3 
Error: Got unexpected status: SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE
```

when creating the channel with the peer channel create command...

I noticed that in the script.sh there are the following instructions

```
# wait for Hyperledger Fabric to start
# incase of errors when running later commands, issue export FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT=<larger number>
export FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT=10
echo ${FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT}
sleep ${FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT}
```

I tried to increase the value of the FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT parameter to 50000
but after a long wait I receive the following error message instead
when creating the channel with the peer channel create ... command

```
Error: timeout waiting for channel creation    
2018-06-29 08:43:09.211 UTC [channelCmd] readBlock -> DEBU 0ca Got status:*orderer.DeliverResponse_Status 
2018-06-29 08:43:09.220 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 0cb Returning existing local MSP
2018-06-29 08:43:09.220 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 0cc Obtaining default signing identity
2018-06-29 08:43:09.349 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 0cd Endorser and orderer connections initialized
2018-06-29 08:43:09.551 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 0ce Returning existing local MSP
2018-06-29 08:43:09.552 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 0cf Obtaining default signing identity
2018-06-29 08:43:09.552 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 0d0 Returning existing local MSP
2018-06-29 08:43:09.552 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 0d1 Obtaining default signing identity
2018-06-29 08:43:09.553 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 0d2 Sign: plaintext: 0AC3060A1508021A06089DE2D7D90522...CC7CC6C6D06B12080A021A0012021A00 
2018-06-29 08:43:09.553 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 0d3 Sign: digest: 42A634D3AFF100309D23252C250AB482336DDA561069E9030B031FC828F9913A 
2018-06-29 08:43:09.555 UTC [channelCmd] readBlock -> DEBU 0d4 Got status:*orderer.DeliverResponse_Status 
2018-06-29 08:43:09.556 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 0d5 Returning existing local MSP
2018-06-29 08:43:09.557 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 0d6 Obtaining default signing identity
2018-06-29 08:43:09.569 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 0d7 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
Error: timeout waiting for channel creation
```

Finally, however, I notice that with both errors (service not available and timeout) the docker containers are correctly executed.
However, the network does not seem to be started correctly

```
    CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                          COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                                                NAMES
f56be7da9b18        hyperledger/fabric-tools       "/bin/bash"              12 minutes ago      Up 12 minutes                                                                                                            cli
d57d63f0b9e9        hyperledger/fabric-peer        "peer node start"        12 minutes ago      Up 12 minutes       0.0.0.0:10051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:33247->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:10053->7053/tcp, 0.0.0.0:33245->7053/tcp   peer1.org2.example.com
165b1f7136cf        hyperledger/fabric-peer        "peer node start"        12 minutes ago      Up 12 minutes       0.0.0.0:8051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:33246->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8053->7053/tcp, 0.0.0.0:33244->7053/tcp     peer1.org1.example.com
05a1d10153fe        hyperledger/fabric-peer        "peer node start"        12 minutes ago      Up 12 minutes       0.0.0.0:9051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:33243->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9053->7053/tcp, 0.0.0.0:33241->7053/tcp     peer0.org2.example.com
96992fd12246        hyperledger/fabric-peer        "peer node start"        12 minutes ago      Up 12 minutes       0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7053->7053/tcp, 0.0.0.0:33242->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:33240->7053/tcp     peer0.org1.example.com
033777e7e3b0        hyperledger/fabric-orderer     "orderer"                12 minutes ago      Up 12 minutes       0.0.0.0:9050->7050/tcp, 0.0.0.0:33239->7050/tcp                                                      orderer2.example.com
7758608083cc        hyperledger/fabric-orderer     "orderer"                12 minutes ago      Up 12 minutes       0.0.0.0:8050->7050/tcp, 0.0.0.0:33238->7050/tcp                                                      orderer1.example.com
7b3afc6ff79f        hyperledger/fabric-orderer     "orderer"                12 minutes ago      Up 12 minutes       0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp, 0.0.0.0:33237->7050/tcp                                                      orderer0.example.com
41b638dbd533        hyperledger/fabric-kafka       "/docker-entrypoint.…"   12 minutes ago      Up 12 minutes       9093/tcp, 0.0.0.0:33236->9092/tcp                                                                    kafka2
11ee7e61adb1        hyperledger/fabric-kafka       "/docker-entrypoint.…"   12 minutes ago      Up 12 minutes       9093/tcp, 0.0.0.0:33235->9092/tcp                                                                    kafka0
f7c1d3ca3b24        hyperledger/fabric-kafka       "/docker-entrypoint.…"   12 minutes ago      Up 12 minutes       9093/tcp, 0.0.0.0:33234->9092/tcp                                                                    kafka1
3655689e2ee6        hyperledger/fabric-kafka       "/docker-entrypoint.…"   12 minutes ago      Up 12 minutes       9093/tcp, 0.0.0.0:33233->9092/tcp                                                                    kafka3
57dbc6c6c9e9        hyperledger/fabric-zookeeper   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   13 minutes ago      Up 12 minutes       0.0.0.0:33231->2181/tcp, 0.0.0.0:33229->2888/tcp, 0.0.0.0:33226->3888/tcp                            zookeeper2
ab6ac8fed33f        hyperledger/fabric-zookeeper   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   13 minutes ago      Up 12 minutes       0.0.0.0:33232->2181/tcp, 0.0.0.0:33230->2888/tcp, 0.0.0.0:33227->3888/tcp                            zookeeper0
2f3cdd4e032c        hyperledger/fabric-zookeeper   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   13 minutes ago      Up 12 minutes       0.0.0.0:33228->2181/tcp, 0.0.0.0:33225->2888/tcp, 0.0.0.0:33224->3888/tcp                            zookeeper1
```

Thanks
corpie

Answer (score 0):

did you check all your kafka/orderer/zookeeper logs to make sure everything there is ok?